# Laravel Eloquent Sum of relation's column

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relation

I've been working on a shopping cart application and now I've come to the following issue..

**There is a User, a Product and a Cart object.**

- The Cart table only contains the following columns: `id`, `user_id`, `product_id` and timestamps.
- The UserModel `hasMany` Carts (because a user can store multiple products).
- The CartModel `belongsTo` a User and CartModel `hasMany` Products.

Now to calculate the total products I can just call: `Auth::user()->cart()->count()`.

My question is: How can I get the `SUM()` of prices (a column of product) of the products in cart by this User?
I would like to accomplish this with Eloquent and not by using a query (mainly because I believe it is a lot cleaner).

Answer (score 322, accepted):

```
Auth::user()->products->sum('price');
```

The documentation is a little light for some of the `Collection` methods but all the query builder aggregates are seemingly available besides `avg()` that can be found at http://laravel.com/docs/queries#aggregates.

Comment: wow thanks for that quick reply. It now just says there is no price column. It looks like eloquent is not looking at that Product table at all....

Comment: Actually that makes sense, you have to add the products table to the relationship, sorry.  Try `$sum = Auth::user()->cart()->products()->sum('price');` or whatever the price column is on your products table.

Comment: Yeah I tried that already, but now it gives something like; "Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::product()" while I'm sure the cart model has a method product() with a hasMany method in it.

Comment: I just tried to replicate the issue, and I think we are making this too hard.  Your `Cart` model is really just the pivot table, so we shouldn't have to include that, as that's taken care of in the `User` and `Product` model with your relationship methods.  `Auth::user()->products->sum('price');`.  Also make sure you are logged in so the Auth class knows which user to grab.  Your cart model probably shouldn't have the `products()` function, as that belongs in the `User` model for this relationship.  You really shouldn't even need a model for `Cart`.

Comment: That worked for me! I stopped using the cartclasses. Both the User and the product now have a belongsToMany() method.   
Now I am able to use price: {{ Auth::user()->products->sum('price') }}
Thanx, This case is solved.

Comment: Okay, I updated my original answer to what worked for you.  Thanks.

Comment: Something isn't quite right here - your link refers to applying aggregate functions to database queries, but `products->sum` implies it is call sum on a collection object, rather than on the builder object returned by products(). It's worth clarifying which one you mean here, and ideally provide a link to explain both.

Comment: When doing this with a many-to-many relationship you can do something similar to `Auth::user()->products->sum('pivot.price')`.

Comment: How I can have both sum and avg both with a single command/query?

Comment: How would you make this into a function on the User class? Is that possible?

Comment: @user3158900 Is there a difference between `Auth::user()->products->sum('price')` and `Auth::user()->products()->sum('price')`?

Comment: @user3253002 using a relationship without parenthesis `...->products->...` will query the database to get all of the current model's related products and then work with that in-memory collection. Using `...->products()->...` just modifies the query being build without executing it until something like `->sum()` is called.The latter can be more efficient, as it avoids transferring unnecessary information from the database into memory.

Answer (score 105):

this is not your answer but is for those come here searching solution for another problem. 
I wanted to get sum of a column of related table conditionally. 
In my database Deals has many Activities 
I wanted to get the sum of the "amount_total" from Activities table where activities.deal_id = deal.id and activities.status = paid
so i did this.

```
$query->withCount([
'activity AS paid_sum' => function ($query) {
            $query->select(DB::raw("SUM(amount_total) as paidsum"))->where('status', 'paid');
        }
    ]);
```

it returns

```
"paid_sum_count" => "320.00"
```

in Deals attribute.

This it now the sum  which i wanted to get not the count.

Comment: This is the best in many cases because you can sort by it without having to get all records.

Comment: Its working fine, But we have to add groupBy() method in above solution..

Comment: This must be accepted answer

Comment: Today there is withSum. The job just got a little easier.

Answer (score 24):

I tried doing something similar, which took me a lot of time before I could figure out the collect() function. So you can have something this way:

`collect($items)->sum('amount');`

This will give you the sum total of all the items.

Comment: the name of the function is actually `collect() `

Comment: you're probably better off just looping the array. `collect()` is used to enrich an array into a collection object, but if you dont have a collection in the first place it might be better to just use the raw array

Answer (score 18):

you can do  it using eloquent easily like this

```
$sum = Model::sum('sum_field');
```

its will return a sum of fields,
if apply condition on it that is also simple

```
$sum = Model::where('status', 'paid')->sum('sum_field');
```

Answer (score 11):

Since version 8, there is a `withSum` method on Eloquent, so you could use this.

```
Auth::user()->withSum('products', 'price')->products_sum_price;
```

This won't load all products into memory and then sum it up with collection method. Rather it will generate a sub query for the database, so it's quicker and uses less memory.

Comment: Works like a charm. Too bad you can't give it a personalized name with this methos :s.

Comment: Yep, and works in laravel 10.

Answer (score 7):

You can pass this as UserModel attribute. Add this code to UserModel.

```
public function getProductPriceAttribute(){
    return $this->cart()->products()->sum('price');
}
```

I assume something like this:

- UserModel has a one to many relationship with a CartModel named **cart**
- CartModel has a one to many relationship with ProductModel named **products**

And then you can get sum price of the product like this:

```
Auth::user()->product_price
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out 11 years after.. I think I can carry on with the project now ;)

Comment: @theAdmiral Love to see a time traveler from 2025

Answer (score 5):

Also using query builder

```
DB::table("rates")->get()->sum("rate_value")
```

To get summation of all rate value inside table rates.

To get summation of user products.

```
DB::table("users")->get()->sum("products")
```

Answer (score 3):

For people who just want to quickly display the total **sum** of the values in a column to the blade view, you can do this:

```
{{ \App\Models\ModelNameHere::sum('column_name') }}
```

You can also do it for **averages**:

```
{{ \App\Models\ModelNameHere::avg('column_name') }}
```

**Min:**

```
{{ \App\Models\ModelNameHere::min('column_name') }}
```

**Max:**

```
{{ \App\Models\ModelNameHere::max('column_name') }}
```

To get the **Count of a table:**

```
{{ \App\Models\ModelNameHere::count() }}
```

Comment: Isn't this a bad Laravel practice to use Model facades in blade files?

Comment: Doesn't really obey MVC