# How to sum nested relation attribute in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm wondering how I can sum the attributes of a multiply-nested relation in Laravel. I'm aware that Laravel has some cool sum functions as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21679678/laravel-eloquent-sum-of-relations-column), but wondering how to take that one level deeper.

My models are set up as follows:

**Projects** have many tasks.

**Tasks** have many logs.

**Logs** have an attribute "duration."

I've queried projects and are iterating through projects in an html table.  I want to display the sum of the log durations.  I was thinking maybe I could do something like:

```
$project->tasks->logs->sum('duration')
```

But that doesn't do it.  Is this possible to do with a single, elegant line like this, or am I going to have to set up a loop and sum "manually"?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From your question I assume you have a chain of `hasMany` relations, so nothing easier:

```
// Project model
public function logs()
{
  return $this->hasManyThrough('Log', 'Task');
  // defaults to:
  // return $this->hasManyThrough('Log', 'Task', 'project_id', 'task_id');
}

// then sum on the query
$project->logs()->sum('duration');

// or on the collection, but don't do it unless you really need that collection
$project->logs->sum('duration');
```

You can see the default `foreign keys` that Eloquent will look for on the models, so adjust them if you don't stick to the Laravel convention.

Comment: i'm looking for the same result, but i have a deeper chain of relations: is there a way to "build" the sum (i also need to put some `where` conditions trough the relations to filer unwanted rows) without creatin a `HasManyRotugh` ad-hoc relation?