# Laravel relationship sum on appends attribute

Tags: laravel, model, laravel-5.6

i have two model

this is my **material** model:

```
<?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class material extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['proposal_id','thickness','width','length','qty','description'];
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $appends = ['total'];
    public function proposal()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(proposal::class);
    }
    public function getTotalAttribute()
    {
        return $this->qty * $this->price;
    }
}
```

this is my **proposal** model:

```
<?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class proposal extends Model
{
    public function materials()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(material::class);
    }
}
```

i'm trying to get all proposal with summary from total attribute which is an appended attribute.

This is not working:

```
\App\proposal::with(['materials'=>function($q){
    $q->sum('total');
    }])
    ->get();
```

how to do it properly?
thank you

Comment: this might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21679678/laravel-eloquent-sum-of-relations-column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$q->sum('total')` part of your code is performing a database query, whilst your `total` attribute is generated on the model and not in the database.

For a quick solution you could add an appended attribute to the `Proposal` model which calculates the total of all it's materials. You will want to be careful doing this as you might run into an N+1 issue (https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading).

Following on from this you could check if `Materials` relationship has been loaded first before calculating the total? Inside your model you can check via `$this->relationLoaded('materials')`.

Lastly but more complicated you could write a custom select which uses MySQL (or whatever database you are using) to generate the total during the query.

Hope that helps? Let me know if you want to discuss further.

Comment: thanks man! the answer is we can't sum on appended attributes so we need to create custom query like you said