# How to collect (mathematically) any number that enters the database

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

I don't know how to explain this in English but i will try my best .

I have a table called invoices and when a user does something a record is added to the table . which is called `Amount` .So i want to know is it possible to add all the records that enters the invoice table ?

like :

```
AMOUNT 1 + AMOUNT 2 + AMOUNT 3 + Keeps going ...
```

And display the total .

I have no idea what to try and what to do . I never did something like this before

is it possible to accomplish this ?

Comment: You mean like some sort of SUM DB function? Most (if not all) databases already provide that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called `Aggregates`

[Laravel Documentation / Aggregates](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#aggregates)

a simple example :

```
$users = DB::table('transactions')
    ->sum('transactions.amount');
```

if you are trying to sum a relationship try something like this :

```
$user->invoices->sum('amount')
```

[Laravel Eloquent Sum of relation's column](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21680118/9323177)

Answer (score 1):

You could make it easy using `sum()` like this one

```
invoice::sum('amount');
```

you can check [laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#aggregates)

Answer (score 0):

You could use Eloquent with your model:

```
$total = Invoice::where('column', 'some condition')->sum('amount');
```

You could use DB builder:

```
$total = DB::table('invoices')->sum('amount');
```

In a relationship

```
Sale::where('column', 'some condition')->with('invoices', function($query){
    $query->sum('amount');
}])->get();
```

You could use sql

```
SELECT SUM(amount) as Total FROM invoices WHERE ...... some condition
```

is that what you need?