# Laravel : How to using group By with sum and select multi field

Tags: php, laravel, group-by

In my Laravel project ,I have users table contain id and username ...etc.
another table called predictors ,both of them related in user_id (one to many),now I want to create array contain username from users table and sum of point field in predictors table.
I tried many thing but don't work like this :

```
public function leader()
    {
    $predects = Predector::selectRaw(' user_id ,sum(point) as points')->groupBy('user_id')->get();
    foreach($predects as $predect){
        $predect->User->username;
    }
    return $predects;
    }
```

but it gave me this result

```
{
    "user_id": 1,
    "points": "3",
    "user": {
        "id": 1,
        "username": "sarmed",
        "nat_id": "123456",
        "email_verified_at": null,
        "created_at": "2020-11-30T17:10:27.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2020-11-30T17:10:27.000000Z"
    }
},
```

and I want something like this :

```
 {
        "user_id": 1,
        "points": "3",
        "username": "sarmed",
    },
```

Comment: Check this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21679678/laravel-eloquent-sum-of-relations-column

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand correctly, goal is to get a sum of all points for a user and then provide a dataset of User's id, points and username

Assuming the relation on User model as

```php
class User extends Model
{
    public function predects()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Predector::class);
    }
}
```

Try the following snippet to achieve the desired output

```php
public function leader()
{
    return User::query()
        ->with('predects:id,user_id,point')
        ->select('id', 'username')
        ->get()
        ->map(function($user){
            $predects = $user->predects;
            unset($user->predects);
            $user->points = $predects->sum('point');
            return $user;
        })
        ->sortByDesc('points')
        ->toArray();
}
```

For Laravel versions below 8.x have a look at Laravel Subquery package
https://github.com/Alexmg86/laravel-sub-query  to simplify things a bit more

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by adding this line :

```
unset($predect->User);
```

now the correct code :

```
public function leader()
    {
        
        $predects = Predector::selectRaw(' user_id ,sum(point) as points')->groupBy('user_id')->orderBy('points','desc')->get();
        foreach($predects as $predect){
            $predect->username=$predect->User->username;
            unset($predect->User);
        }
        return $predects;
    }
```

and the result is :

```
[
    {
        "user_id": 2,
        "points": "7",
        "username": "sermedov"
    },
    {
        "user_id": 1,
        "points": "3",
        "username": "sarmed"
    }
]
```