# Laravel: How to calculate sum of column values using eloquent?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to use `sum()` get the sum of column value, but unfortunately it isn't working and I can't figure out where I am wrong.

```
$total = Invoice::where('status', 'Completed')
             ->sum('amount');
```

This returns error `Call to a member function first() on string`

**invoices (Table)**

| id | code | status | amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 000001 | Completed | 300.00 |
| 2 | 000002 | Completed | 500.00 |
| 3 | 000003 | Pending | 100.00 |

I want to display the sum of invoices' amount in the view.

**Blade View**

| Activity | Count | Total Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Invoices | 6 | **900.00** |

Comment: the `amount` column is numeric type?

Comment: @sta is float type

Comment: it could be a typo `where('status', 'Completed')` => `where('Status', 'Completed')` because your column name is `Status` not `status`

Comment: sorry I mistake, my table column name is in lowercase for all, so it shouldn't be a typo error..

Comment: see this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/21680118/7555850

Comment: please share the code that displays the amount using `$total`

Comment: `$total = Invoice::where('status', 'Completed')->sum('amount');` this is the code i use to displays the amount

Comment: Are you sure that line is generating that error?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$total = Invoice::select(
DB::raw(SUM(amount) as total_amount)
)->where('status', 'Completed')->pluck('total_amount');
```

and foreach the value in the view file like:

```
@foreach(total as total_value)
<td>{{total_value}}</td>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

```
convert the `amount` attribute into Int before storing into database.for example 
$amount = $request->amount;
$invoice = new Invoice();
$invoice->amount = (int)$amount;
--
--
--
$invoice->save();
```

then you can use the above query for column sum