# Laravel DB table - binding related information. Is there a better way here?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent-relationship

I have tables "Seminars", "Users" and "UserSeminarAttendance".

Users can sign up for a seminar. They can take multiple tickets (think user + child + another parent etc).

The "UserSeminarAttendance" table stores the seminar ID, user ID who made the purchase, + number of tickets the user wants.

I want to know how many tickets have been taken for a seminar, and apply this sum as a virtual parameter in the Seminar object. This is easy enough:

```
$tickets = 0;
$attendance_rows = UserSeminarAttendance::where( "seminar_id", $seminarid )->get();
foreach($attendance_rows as $row){
   $tickets += (int) $row->num_tickets;
}
$s->numAttendances = $tickets;
```

..this works. But is there a better way using a model relation? Ideally I always want there to be a ticket count in the seminar request, but I don't want to perform the extra DB request + a foreach every time.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel Eloquent Sum of relation's column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21679678/laravel-eloquent-sum-of-relations-column)

Comment: Specifically [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71653922/1255289). Assuming your relation is named "attendance" then all you need to do is `Seminar::find($seminarid)->withSum('attendance', 'num_tickets')->get()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your models are set up like this:

```
class Seminar extends Model
{
    // Define the relationship
    public function attendance()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(UserSeminarAttendance::class, 'seminar_id');
    }

    // Define an accessor to get the sum of tickets
    public function getNumAttendancesAttribute()
    {
        return $this->attendance->sum('num_tickets');
    }
}
```

UserSeminarAttendance model:

```
class UserSeminarAttendance extends Model
{
    // Your model definition
}
```

Now, when you retrieve a Seminar instance, you can access the total number of tickets directly without explicitly querying the database or using a foreach loop:

```
$seminar = Seminar::find($seminarId);
$numAttendances = $seminar->numAttendances;
```

Laravel will automatically perform the necessary SQL query to get the sum of tickets associated with that seminar, making your code cleaner and more efficient.

Comment: Perfect, thanks that's exactly what I was looking for. What if I remove the num_tickets column and just want to use a general counter. Would I just use $this->attendance->count() ?

Comment: If you remove the num_tickets column and want to use the count of attendance instead, you can modify the getNumAttendancesAttribute method in your Seminar model to directly return the count:
 `public function getNumAttendancesAttribute() { 
return $this->attendance->count();
 }`
 With this modification, you'll get the total count of attendance for the seminar. When you access the numAttendances attribute, it will return the number of attendance records associated with that seminar. 
`$seminar = Seminar::find($seminarId); $numAttendances = $seminar->numAttendances;`

Comment: Great, many thanks again!